# What is the wrong with my code for the StairCase challenge on HackerRank?

Tags: java

Here is my main method in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            //n is the number of height
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                //print out spaces
                while(j < n - i)
                    {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    j++;
                }
                while(k < (n - j + 1))
                    {
                    System.out.print("#");
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: no, you tell us whats wrong, and you may ask why you cannot fix it

Comment: This code is not accepted by HackerRank even though the output is the same.

Comment: urm not everyone here knows HackerRank. what is the requirement?

Comment: I don't know how to show the image of the staircase. You can find the requirement here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase

Comment: @T.McGee update your question above

Comment: That doesn't look like a staircase at all.

Comment: @ajb What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that in the comment that you cleverly deleted after I posted my comment, your output didn't look like a staircase.

Comment: Are you sure the output is the same?  Since you are printing spaces, it may be hard to tell just by looking at the output whether it's exactly the same.

Comment: Ok I am one of the Hiring Team from HackerRank and you won't get hired -_-

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. And @Baby, this is not for getting hired at HackerRank.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing space for the last line also.
You can replace space with some other visible character and check output.
Here is accepted solution.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
                if(j>=n-i+1)
                    System.out.print("#");
                else System.out.print(" ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @user3747720

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code. It's gathering the whole string and printing it at the end.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int _n;
        _n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        StairCase(_n);
    }

    static void StairCase(int n)
    {
        string s = "";

        if (n > 0 && n < 101)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                s = StairCase(s, i + 1);
                if (i + 1 < n)
                {
                    s += string.Format("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string StairCase(string s, int n)
    {
        int c = n;
        while (c > 0)
        {
            s += string.Format("#");
            c = c - 1;
        }
        return s;
    }
```